# How do I find mail messages in an inbox with UTF-7 character encoding

Tags: parsing, imap, utf-7

We have a script that moves messages from an inbox into a CRM against the contact record of the sender (nice one CiviCRM!)

It has stopped working because someone has sent us a message in UTF-7 encoding, and the script can't or won't convert it to UTF-8

We now have a backlog of over a thousand messages.

How do we find the needle in this Inbox?

Does anyone know a script that will produce a report listing any messages in UTF-7 encoding, or of any other sneaky way to find the offending messsage(s)?

Comment: The message is in UTF-7?  That's.... exceedingly odd.  That should be declared in the Content-Type of the relevant MIME section of the message.  So, you could do a BODYSTRUCTURE query for all messages in the mailbox (``[tag] FETCH 1:* (BODYSTRUCTURE``), and try to identify any that mention UTF-7 encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response, Max - yep, very odd - but there are no messages that stand out as really odd to a human being. - I'm searching google for what a BODYSTRUCTURE query is!

Comment: Agh - so anything that will look through the header files - yes, but I can't work out how to query the encoding - any ideas?

Comment: When looking at raw source I can see some have charset=UTF-8 included as a parameter of Content-Type - but so far using rules in a mail client hasn't found an answer..

Comment: Oh, you're trying to do this from a mail client.  This should be on the system administration (serverfault) or end user (superuser) overflow.  This one is specifically for programming, so I thought you were interacting with IMAP directly.